# exception when i am trying to fill table with date value from excel file java

Tags: java, jdbc

i am trying to make a program where i would read data from excel files and store them in tables. I have multiple files and the code works fine for most of them. But when I trying  the files that contain date  columns I have some problems.

Firstly for showing the data in my console I have made the code below for the different types of data:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "dd/MM/yyyy");
                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    } else {
                        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        Long longValue = value.longValue();
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    System.out.print("null");
                }
```

Furthermore, when I parse the data I am using the code below for the different types of data:

```
if (cell != null) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                            tableFields.put(String.valueOf(cell
                                    .getDateCellValue()), cell.getCellType());
                        } else {

                            tableFields
                                    .put(String.valueOf(cell
                                            .getNumericCellValue()), cell
                                            .getCellType());
                        }
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        tableFields.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), cell
                                .getCellType());
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        tableFields.put(String.valueOf(cell
                                .getBooleanCellValue()), cell.getCellType());
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                        tableFields.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), cell
                                .getCellType());

                    }
```

When I create the table:

```
switch (fieldType) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                str = fieldName + " dateFormat";

                str = fieldName + " INTEGER";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                str = fieldName + " VARCHAR(255)";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                str = fieldName + " INTEGER";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                str = "null";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
```

And in the end when I am filling the table with the values I am using the code below:

```
switch (fieldType) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    str = fieldValue;
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    str = "\'" + fieldValue + "\'";
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    str = fieldValue;
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    str = "null";
                    break;
                default:
                    str = "";
                    break;
                }
```

But when I am running the program I get this exception:

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Apr 21 00:00:00 EEST 1987)' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064
```

Could anyone help me why i get it?
The date has form: 26/4/1980

Comment: Can you show us where you use the dateFormat instance?

Comment: You are trying to get values from an excel file and add them into a SQL table?

Comment: yes! I am trying to read all the data form excel files and store them in tables in mysql.

Comment: And what do you don't understand from `You have an error in your SQL syntax`? :S It's obviusly because your **QUERY** it's not working properly. I suggest you to use a query tracker to see when and how your query is built or a simple `System.out.println(query)`. Maybe you forgot something like a `'`, `(`, etc. or post your query to try  to find the error.

Comment: That's why i am asking here. Because obviously i can't find it. And as i mention in my question i get this only when my file contain date column.

Comment: ... probably I was not clear. To do something like what you are trying to do, you have to do something like: `String sql = "SELECT..."; preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);`, right? Before you set the `preparedStatement` write `System.out.println(sql);` and update your question with the SQL query that you are trying to send to MySQL. You can change column names, etc. for security

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

in

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You insert Date (as example `Apr 21 00:00:00 EEST 1987`) to `INTEGER` type column. You can use `DATETIME` mysql type for date in string (with `'`) or `DECIMAL` for the number of milliseconds represented by date value from excel file.

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Apr 21 00:00:00 EEST 1987)' at line 1
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what I have to change?